# How to test if a piece of code refers to a macro in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

In clojure is there something like "is-macro?" to test to see if something is a macro?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given a var, its metadata can tell you whether it's a macro:

```
(:macro (meta #'when))
=> true
(:macro (meta #'identity))
=> nil
```